# Allowing draggable to move only in 20px squares

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Basically I have two containers, whose background is a repeating box 20x20 pixels. I want to allow the draggables to be able to move only if aligned with these 20x20 squares. I found a solution that suits but for some reason doesn't quite work the rest of the code.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
drag: function( event, ui ) {
            var snapTolerance = $(this).draggable('option', 'snapTolerance');
            var topRemainder = ui.position.top % 20;
            var leftRemainder =ui.position.left % 20;

            if (topRemainder <= snapTolerance) {
                ui.position.top = ui.position.top - topRemainder;
            }

            if (leftRemainder <= snapTolerance) {
                ui.position.left = ui.position.left - leftRemainder;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I don't want the boxes to touch when dropped inside some of the containers. For which I use the following function

```
for(var i=1; i<=15; i++){
$('#box-' + i).droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){

        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);

    }

})
```

};

Both of them work fine individually, together they just don't :D. Here's an example of what happens sometimes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrbm7.jpg [sry, can't post images :(]

Another nasty bug is that sometimes even if placed right inside the container, the box returns to its previous position, as if it wasn't allowed to be dropped there.

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rb4qeq8k/4/

So the question is, is there any other way of making the boxes move only in 20px steps so that they're always aligned with the container's squares, that doesn't bug like this one?

EDIT: I came to the conclusion that the snapTolerance somehow bugs and checks cursor's moves not the object position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the doc !

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

`$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20, 20 ] });`